# How to achieve WS-Security in Android over SOAP Service

Tags: java, android, web-services, security, soap

We' re trying to call the SOAP Web Service securely from Android. Have utilized KSoap2 library to consume the Web Service.

However achieving the message level security with the utilization of Digital Certificate has been a big Question mark?

Like to know if KSoap2 supports WS-Security with Digital Certificates?

Alternative to KSoap2 could be easyWSDL [which Consumes  Soap Services by generating Stubs] but does  easyWSDL supports WS-Security?